# git-gutter dont show sign

Tags: magit-status

I just install Emacs with magit & git-gutter.
Initialise a git repo then create and manipulate some files but I cannot see any sign.
I hit

> magit-status
> Then stage and commit and make some changes (add, modify and delete lines) then save but nothing happen.

My init.el:

```
(use-package magit
 :ensure t)
(use-package git-gutter
  :ensure t)

(require 'git-gutter)

;; If you enable global minor mode
(global-git-gutter-mode t)

;; If you would like to use git-gutter.el and linum-mode
(git-gutter:linum-setup)

(custom-set-variables
 '(git-gutter:update-interval 2))

(custom-set-variables
 '(git-gutter:modified-sign "=") ;; two space
 '(git-gutter:added-sign "+")    ;; multiple character is OK
 '(git-gutter:deleted-sign "-"))

(set-face-background 'git-gutter:modified "#0174fc") ;; background color
(set-face-foreground 'git-gutter:added "#64a888")
(set-face-foreground 'git-gutter:deleted "#c5332c")
```

I dont have any other packages installed.

[image]

Emacs 27.1 (build1, x86_64_pc-linux-gnu) GTK+ Version 3.24.30, cairo version 1.16.0)

Comment: Calling `require` is unnecessary as you have already called `use-package` for it, but that won’t prevent it from working either. Calling `(global-git-gutter-mode t)` was all I needed to do to get it working, but then I don’t use `linum-mode`. Perhaps they don’t work together properly? The webpage says that this is experimental, so perhaps try without it.

Comment: I disabled linum-mode and seems working fine.  Thank

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of proper way to do with **use-package**

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq magit-push-always-verify nil)
  (setq git-commit-summary-max-length 50)
  :bind ("C-x g" . magit-status))

(use-package git-gutter
  :ensure t
  :hook ((prog-mode org-mode) . git-gutter-mode )
  :config
  (setq git-gutter:update-interval 2)
  (setq git-gutter:modified-sign "†")
  (setq git-gutter:added-sign "†")
  (setq git-gutter:deleted-sign "†")
  (set-face-foreground 'git-gutter:added "Green")
  (set-face-foreground 'git-gutter:modified "Gold")
  (set-face-foreground 'git-gutter:deleted "Red"))
```